# Different types of Xcode applications

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I am new to Xcode development. When I first opened Xcode 4.2, there were different types of applications we can build (Master Detail, Page Based, Single View, Tabbed, Utility, Empty Application) using Xcode.

I am somewhat confused about how different they are from each other. I did some search but so far I am not able to understand their basic difference. How would I know which application to select to start developing my own application.

If someone can explain their difference and usage to me in layman terms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Those are different starter template's provided along with Xcode. You may decide not to you use any of the templates and go with an empty project.

Below is the brief overview of each of the templates.

Master Detail - Template which has pre-created Parent-child views with navigation controller, typically for iPad for different orientation.

Page based - Similar to iBooks app.

Single View - Starter template with a single view. you can add multiple view whenever required.

Tabbed application - View controller with tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

I hope you got the idea. In my opinion, as a starter, you should go with creating a single view based application.

Good luck.